# Appfog app: delete file

Tags: linux, terminal, delete-file, appfog

I registered [Appfog](http://appfog.com), for sharing my web applications and made login with linux terminal commands, but exists one problem, I didn't find way to fix this.
I want to delete files or directories in my appfog application using terminal commands, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any documentation regarding deletion. Since it works on the principle of git, you could just delete the file you wan to delete from your local directory and run the `af update appname` command. That should do it.